# How to convert mpeg-4 to mp3 or wave format using pure python on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mp3, mpeg-4

I'm working on a project, using Python running on Google App Engine. The project must allow users to upload mpeg-4 audio file for others to playback. Is there a way to convert mpeg-4 to mp3/wav on the server side?

Could anyone offer a solution to this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some quick research has shown me that just about everything you can find written in python that converts audio has external dependencies. This would indicate to me that there are currently no libraries to do this in pure python and none on their way. You may consider looking for a web service to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine is designed for lightweight HTTP requests and user-facing Web application.
Video/audio transcoding is an **Heavy activity** that would probably deplete your available CPU quota in no time.
If you can, outsource the transcoding Task to some third-party service like [Zencoder](http://zencoder.com/), [Heywatch](http://heywatch.com/page/home) or [Encoding.com](http://encoding.com) .

Comment: +1. Even if there was something to do it in pure Python (and good encoders are a lot of work, so nobody's likely to write one in Python), it would be orders of magnitude less efficient than doing it in native code.